# Motion of a charged particle in a constant and uniform magnetic field

Tags: special-relativity, classical-electrodynamics

Assuming the following relationship has been demonstrated

$$r=\frac{m u_{0}\sin \theta_0}{qB\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{u_{0}^2}{c^2}\right)}}=\frac{p_0\sin \theta_0}{qB}$$

[image]

where $p_0=mu_0/\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$ represents the relativistic momentum of the particle. In the relativistic case, therefore, $\omega$ (relativistic angular velocity $\omega=\frac{qB}{m} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{u_{0}^2}{c^2}\right)^2}$) is no longer constant but depends on the speed $\bar{u}_{0}$ of the charged particle $q$; in fact the factor $\gamma$ is present.

The step $p$ (different of the momentum $p_0$) is obtained from the product of the parallel component of the initial particle speed $u_{0\parallel}$ and the period $T$:

$$p=(u_{0})_zT=u_{0\parallel}T$$

Making some considerations about the angle $\theta_0$, if $\theta_0=0$ why I obtain a straight line? Don't you have $r=0$?

Comment: Why do some users want to close my question? Is there a reason?

Comment: It isn’t clear what $r$ is the radius of, what $\theta_0$ is the angle between, what $\omega$ is supposed to be, and how $\bar{u}$, $u_0$, and $u$ differ.

Comment: Also, in relativity, $u_0$ and $p_0$ usually mean the covariant time component of the four-momentum, but I don’t think you’re using them that way.

Comment: Finally, I don’t think you mean “$\omega$ is no longer constant”. You seem to mean “$\omega$ is no longer speed-independent”.

Comment: So, overall, the question is quite unclear.

Comment: Finally, why do you think that $r=0$ is incompatible with a straight line in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @G.Smith Now my question is more clear?

Comment: The diagram you added helps a lot. Now, what is the difference between $u_0$, $u$, and $\bar{u}$?

Comment: Although the diagram cleared up the meaning of $r$ and $\theta_0$, it introduced a confusion about $p$.

Comment: @G.Smith I think that there is an error on my question: $u_0=u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\theta_0$ is zero, the trajectory is no longer a spiral *around* the $z$-axis; it is a straight line *along* the $z$-axis, for which $r=0$ in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Finally a fair and kind user! It is impossible that in my recent questions I am targeted and how in this question I want to close what I write. I invite you to come to TeX.SE. I signed up to help others but not to have the gift of omnipotence.

Comment: Kindest ("Gentilissimo") user thank you once again for your courteous reply. I will be happy to receive your possible answer on my old or recent questions. Thank you for everything and good work.